# Placing a Query Function into a Script that I could activate with a button

Tags: search, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I am working on a Searching page for a call log my team fills out using a Query Function. What was making it complicated was that I  with some help from these boards I was able to generate the following function and it is working well

```
Iferror(QUERY({'Jan 2020'!A3:R5000;'Feb 2020'!A3:R5000;'Mar 2020'!A3:R5000}, "select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7,Col8,Col9,Col10,Col11,Col12,Col13,Col14,Col15,Col16,Col17,Col18 WHERE "&TEXTJOIN(" and ", 1,IF(B5<>"", "Col1 >= date '"&B6&"'", ),IF(C5<>"", "Col1 <= date '"&C6&"'", ),IF(D5<>"", "Col3 = '"&D5&"'", ),IF(E5<>"", "Col4 = '"&E5&"'", ),IF(F5<>"", "Col5 = '"&F5&"'", ),IF(B8<>"", "Col6 = '"&B8&"'", ),IF(C8<>"", "Col9= '"&C8&"'", ),IF(D8<>"", "Col10= '"&D8&"'", ),
IF(E8<>"", "Col11= '"&E8&"'", )),1),"No Match")
```

The issue that I am running into is that I would like the be able to fill out the Search areas and then press a button to activate the function to run. Right now every time I change one of the search terms the page will update with each change. So if I am changing 3 search perimeters I have to wait for Sheets to update each for each change. As you can see our teams are averaging about 4000 calls a month so this can be time consuming for the script to read.

I was thinking that I could simply place this Query into a Scrip and have that Script activated by a "Search" Button.

I am still fairly new to scripting and am getting confused by what I am finding online because it seems to me that they need to build the function from scratch in script language.

Is there a way to simply write a script to activate the function?

I was thinking possible just having it paste the function into the cell I would need it to activate in and then maybe having a clear script set to a "Reset Search" button.

Comment: Can you share a sanitised copy of your sheet please?

Comment: Sorry about that, here you go [Tester Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1olFfUS1XeVudiJpSoKGHyBjWPUp3cawEiVxgli6GDs8/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1):

#### Answer:

*You can create two functions and assign them to 'search' and 'clear' buttons. One pastes the formula into the sheet, and the other replaces the formula with the display values of its return.*

#### Code:

First, create two functions in your script, changing the cell and sheet name strings as required.

```js
function searchFormula() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Copy of Exm") // change for the sheet name
  var cell = sheet.getRange("A17") // change for the cell the function should be in

  var formula = "Iferror(QUERY({'Jan 2020'!A3:R5000;'Feb 2020'!A3:R5000;'Mar 2020'!A3:R5000}, \"select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7,Col8,Col9,Col10,Col11,Col12,Col13,Col14,Col15,Col16,Col17,Col18 WHERE \"&TEXTJOIN(\" and \", 1,IF(B5<>\"\", \"Col1 >= date '\"&B6&\"'\", ),IF(C5<>\"\", \"Col1 <= date '\"&C6&\"'\", ),IF(D5<>\"\", \"Col3 = '\"&D5&\"'\", ),IF(E5<>\"\", \"Col4 = '\"&E5&\"'\", ),IF(F5<>\"\", \"Col5 = '\"&F5&\"'\", ),IF(B8<>\"\", \"Col6 = '\"&B8&\"'\", ),IF(C8<>\"\", \"Col9= '\"&C8&\"'\", ),IF(D8<>\"\", \"Col10= '\"&D8&\"'\", ),\r\nIF(E8<>\"\", \"Col11= '\"&E8&\"'\", )),1),\"No Match\")"

  cell.setFormula(formula);

}

function clearFormula() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Copy of Exm")

  // in the following line the 17 and the 1 should be replaced with the 
  // corresponding cell from the searchFormula() function
  // for example A17 should be .getRange(17, 1 ...)
  // and cell B20 should be .getRange(20, 2 ...) etc
  var range = sheet.getRange(17, 1, sheet.getLastRow() - 1, sheet.getLastColumn() - 1)
  
  range.setValues(range.getDisplayValues());  
}
```

You can then assign the scripts to buttons in the Sheets UI.

#### References:

- [Class `Range` | Apps Script | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range)
- [`Range.setFormula()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setformulaformula)
- [`Range.getDisplayValues()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalues)
- [Class `Sheet` | Apps Script | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet)
- [`Sheet.getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns)